# ld: library not found for -lqscintilla2

Tags: qt, linker, shared-libraries, homebrew, qscintilla

Debug steps:

```
brew uninstall qscintilla2
brew install qscintilla2
```

When that didn't work, I uninstalled again and then manually built from src:

```
curl -OL 'https://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pyqt/QScintilla2/QScintilla-2.10.1/QScintilla_gpl-2.10.1.tar.gz'
tar xf QScintilla_gpl-2.10.1.tar.gz
cd QScintilla_gpl-2.10.1/Qt4Qt5
qmake
make
make install
```

When that didn't work, I tried:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/libqscintilla2_qt5.13.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/libqscintilla.dylib
for f in /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/*.dylib;
    do ln -s "$f" "/usr/local/lib/${f##*/}";
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops, was missing one more symbolic link:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/libqscintilla2_qt5.13.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/libqscintilla2.dylib
```